# One line if/else in Javascript for Sequelize query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, if-statement, sequelize.js

I have working if/else that looks like this:

```
 async invoke(request, response) {
        const { deleted } = request.query;
        let users = [];
        if (deleted === 'true') {
            users = await User.findAndCountAll({
                where: {
                    deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null }
                }
            });
        } else if (deleted === 'false') {
            users = await User.findAndCountAll({
                where: {
                    deletedAt: null
                }
            });
        }

        return response.send(users);
    }
```

I am trying to make it one liner but the problem is { deleted } returning "undefined" and "true", and I need it to return "true" and "false

async invoke(request, response) {
const { deleted } = request.query;

```
    const deletedAt = deleted ? { [Op.not]: null } : null;

    const users = await User.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            deletedAt
        }
    });

    return response.send(users);
}
```

Comment: Is your `deleted` value really a **string**? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** that the only two valid states for `deleted` are `"true"` and `"false"` (odd that it's a string), then since the only difference in the `findAndCountAll` calls is the value of `deletedAt`, you can use the conditional operator:

```
async invoke(request, response) {
    const { deleted } = request.query;
    let users = await User.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            deletedAt: deleted === 'true' ? { [Op.not]: null } : null
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    });

    return response.send(users);
}
```